# Pivot Faceting on multiple fields gives me proper count and 1st record . Is it possible to get all the records?

Tags: solr, solr6

This is my query:

select?q=TYPE:event_time:[2018-04-09T12:36:15.054Z%20TO%202018-04-09T12:36:20.054Z]&fq=FRUIT:*Apple*&facet.pivot=PROVIDER,SUMMARY&facet=on&facet=true&facet.field=PROVIDER&wt=json

Comment: Exactly how does facet.pivot give you the first record? Facets does not return any records - but your regular _query_ will do. It'll return the number of records as you request in the `rows` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> select?q=TYPE:event_time:[2018-04-09T12:36:15.054Z%20TO%202018-04-09T12:36:20.054Z]&fq=FRUIT:Apple&facet.pivot=PROVIDER,SUMMARY&facet=on&facet=true&facet.field=PROVIDER&wt=json&start=0&rows=10

so essentially you have to specify the `start` and `rows` param. In the above query it will return you the first 10 documents.

Read more about these params and pagination here.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/pagination-of-results.html